# Flutter http MultipartRequest field can not be Chinese Charaters?

Tags: http, dart, flutter, multipartform-data

I try to post a form to server and here is the code:

```
ar request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", _uri);
request.fields['user_acc'] = _userAcc;
// this issue should be solve
request.fields['user_nick_name'] = '中文名字';
request.fields['user_password'] = _password;
```

But the server side in the user_nick_name field always got null, note that is **always**, but I change it into English the server can receive that. I test on postman, the server can got Chinese correctly, so it's MultipartRequest issue on this problem.

My question is: **Why the Dart or Flutter team so careless on this so important basic library?** They even not consider about this simply issue. I opened a issue on github but no-one response, I think the team is done. So I ask the develop communit here, how to solve this problem anyway?

**[UPDATE]**
As kindly people suggested, I update my golang server now, if anyone else got this problem, you may wonna answer and suggestions too.

```
func HandleUserRegister(context *gin.Context) {

userAcc := context.PostForm("user_acc")
userAvatar := context.PostForm("user_avatar")
userNickName := context.PostForm("user_nick_name")
userPassword := context.PostForm("user_password")
userPhone := context.PostForm("user_phone")
userEmail := context.PostForm("user_email")
userGender := context.PostForm("user_gender")
userSign := context.PostForm("user_sign")

userType := context.PostForm("user_type")
userTypeInt, _ := strconv.Atoi(userType)

log.Infof("userAcc: %s, userNickName: %s, userPassword: %s", userAcc, userNickName, userPassword)}
```

This is based on gin, and this function is the api solver. If anyone wanna help, please help me figure it out.

OK! I update the question now, **because it's really weird!**. I did those test:

1. Post multiform via Flutter to Django server, it receives Chinese filed correctly;
2. Post multiform data via Postman, the golang(gin) server gots Chinese correctly;
3. Post multiform data via Flutter to golang(gin) server gots **Chinese field null**;

For more detail, I log the headers from my server for both postman(normal) and flutter (abnormal):

**Postman**:

`request header: map[Content-Type:[multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------022341683711652813100488] Postman-Token:[855646d7-5bea-4b8f-b8df-81366226cd49] User-Agent:[PostmanRuntime/7.1.1] Content-Length:[422] Connection:[keep-alive] Cache-Control:[no-cache] Accept:[*/*] Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate]]`

**Flutter**:

`request header: map[User-Agent:[Dart/2.0 (dart:io)] Content-Type:[multipart/form-data; boundary=dart-http-boundary-.XUeYeqXpg4Yfyh8QhH1T5JB4zi_f3WxX9t7Taxhw91EFqhyki4] Accept-Encoding:[gzip] Content-Length:[574]]`

Does anyone can notice the difference and let me know how to change the it make server can receive the Chinese Characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now solved this. Thanks to Richard and Danny for their help.

### 1. Reason for this

No matter what happens but this really not only one-side problem, we can not say it's Flutter or Go wrong. But the combination, Flutter + Go server just may be got this issue. The behind reason I still not quit sure, but it must some head not right set (postman can do it right);

### 2. Solution

We don't only need know why but also how to solve it. Here is what I do:

**Do not use the official http package**. Using `dio`, which is a extension Dart package. link: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio

It's more clean and easy to use, so my code becomes to:

```
 FormData _formData = new FormData.from({
  "user_acc": _userAcc,
  "user_nick_name": _userNickName,
  'user_password': _password,
});

Dio dio = new Dio();
Response response = await dio.post(usersUrl, data: _formData);
print(response.data);
```

I can not post the none-English words now:

```
INFO[0668] userAcc: ww, userNickName: 小鹿叮叮婴儿湿巾手口专用80抽湿纸巾婴儿湿巾婴儿100抽带盖批发【原价】34.90元【券后】9.9元【省】25元【复制此信息打开手机淘宝即可查看并下单】￥Tnsx0E77pFs￥【必买理由】新品预售80抽*3仙女联盟，更多优惠fd.loliloli.pro    , userPassword: ww
```

INFO[0671] user exist.

Answer (score 4):

I tested by posting to httpbin and the response suggests that the characters were posted correctly:

[image: MultipartRequest]

> "user_nick_name":"\u4e2d\u6587\u540d\u5b57"

I tried with both the Stable v1 SDK and a v2 SDK from Flutter. Is it possible the issue is on the server? Have you tried using something like Fiddler to capture what's actually being sent?

**Edit:** My guess is that your server side code is not correctly reading the data as MultipartForm data (eg. you should be using `ParseMultipartForm` and reading from `MultipartForm`).

Comment: I think you are just log the response, but the server got it just null. I am 100% sure that using postman tool, server can get the charators, but with flutter just fail, your experiment can not prove your server got that field correct, more investigation should be made. If you test with your simple server (local or remote) you will got a null in Chinese charaters.

Comment: @NicholasJela I am just logging the response; but that still proves the data got to the server. If the server got null, how could it send it back to me in the response?

Comment: If you're certain that it works from postman, I would log the request sent by Dart and compare it with the one you're sending via postman, and change them one bit at a time until they match, to figure out what's different that causes one to work and the other one not to.

Comment: Hi Danny. I am already logged out on my server, it's none **only** when none-English charator appears, if it is English, then can be received. I still don't know why. I do this in flutter not pure Dart codes.

Comment: @NicholasJela Based on your edit, I still think the problem is your server code. I think you should be using `ParseMultipartForm` and reading from `MultipartForm` (however I've never used Go). I think if you compared the requests being sent by postman and your Dart code, it'll be more obvious. I still think it's unlikely to be a Dart/Flutter bug though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated it again. Did u notice any wrong with my headers? I though there maybe an encoding problem. The server side can got postman data though, so my method might not be wrong.

Comment: You need to compare the full request (headers_body). The explanation for why your postman works seems to be in Richard's answer and comments.

Answer (score 4):

@DannyTuppeny is correct. This is a server problem.

When asked to include a non-ASCII field into a multi-part request, the Dart library correctly wraps this with a binary content-transfer-encoding.

```
  String _headerForField(String name, String value) {
    var header =
        'content-disposition: form-data; name="${_browserEncode(name)}"';
    if (!isPlainAscii(value)) {
      header = '$header\r\n'
          'content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n'
          'content-transfer-encoding: binary';
    }
    return '$header\r\n\r\n';
  }
```

(Postman does not and simply sends the utf8 encoded string without any headers.)

Dart/ASCII looks like this:

```
--dart-http-boundary-HjDS88CmQicdgd8VaHSwPqJK8iR4H6rTG3LovSZy-QXGpU7pAB0
content-disposition: form-data; name="test"

stackover
--dart-http-boundary-HjDS88CmQicdgd8VaHSwPqJK8iR4H6rTG3LovSZy-QXGpU7pAB0
```

Dart/non-ASCII looks like this:

```
First boundary: --dart-http-boundary-58NU6u6_Fo22xjH8H7yPCtKuoKgB+A8+RTJ82iIK1gs3nnGMLlp\r\n
Encapsulated multipart part:  (text/plain)
    content-disposition: form-data; name="test"\r\n
    content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n
    content-transfer-encoding: binary\r\n\r\n
    Line-based text data: text/plain
        \344\270\255\346\226\207\345\220\215\345\255\227
Boundary: \r\n--dart-http-boundary-58NU6u6_Fo22xjH8H7yPCtKuoKgB+A8+RTJ82iIK1gs3nnGMLlp\r\n
```

So the problem is that the server is unable to unwrap the value from the encapsulation.

EDIT
Here's the Postman trace I captured yesterday. It's multi-form, but fails to add the content-type-encoding header despite the field being non-ASCII.

```
MIME Multipart Media Encapsulation, Type: multipart/form-data, Boundary: "--------------------------595246000077585285134204"
    [Type: multipart/form-data]
    First boundary: ----------------------------595246000077585285134204\r\n
    Encapsulated multipart part: 
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"\r\n\r\n
        Data (12 bytes)

0000  e4 b8 ad e6 96 87 e5 90 8d e5 ad 97               ............
            Data: e4b8ade69687e5908de5ad97
            [Length: 12]
    Last boundary: \r\n----------------------------595246000077585285134204--\r\n
```

Comment: Out of interest, why do you say that postman does it right, when it doesn't use content transfer encoding, and it should be? Presumably you should be posing this question to the server side, as to why it can't cope with content transfer encoding.

Comment: @NicholasJela We're trying to help you. We took time out of our day to actually write code and run it and test it for you. If you consider this "not even doing any research" and "not providing a solution or experiment" then I'm afraid I can't help any further.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny Thanks for your guys help, but we still need an answer, I believe there maybe many people stuck on this for days. To save all of us time I shall update an answer myself.

Comment: @NicholasJela The problem is on the server. What Dart is sending is totally valid; you just need to make sure the server interprets it correctly or you need to restructure how you're sending the content. Nobody can help you without knowing what your server is doing, because the Dart code is functioning as expected.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny However, I logged the query params out on my server side, it's also null. I will dig more deeper on this trouble.

Comment: I updated my server code, it's a simple function in golang

Comment: I don't know anything about Golang, but on [this page](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) there is some stuff about calling `ParseMultipartForm` and then using `MultipartForm` instead of `PostForm` for multi-part posts? It would be useful for you to post your PostMan example, is it using multipart forms?

Comment: @DannyTuppeny - updated the answer with the Postman trace I caught yesterday. It is multiform, but postman fails to correctly encode the non-ASCII data. As you say, it looks like Nick should be using ParseMultipartForm.

Comment: @RichardHeap I meant for the OP to.. It seems likely there is a difference between what he's sending with postman and what Dart is sending - if he compares the two I think it'll be obvious what the difference is any why one works (and as you say, it's likely he's not using `ParseMultipartForm` and reading from `MultipartForm`).

Comment: @DannyTuppeny Indeed, my "research" had revealed exactly that ;-)  I answered to amplify your answer - and as somewhere to paste the wireshark fragments that showed the differences that your answer predicted. There's no difference when the field is 100% ASCII, but when it includes UTF-8 chars, Dart correctly wraps it in `content-transfer-encoding: binary` header. RFC-2046 says "Note that if the specified character set includes 8-bit characters and such characters are used in the body, a Content-Transfer-Encoding header field and a corresponding encoding on the data are required..."

Comment: @RichardHeap See my question updates, is there any futhur solution with the content-type wrong settings? I think it still because of the wrong headers

Comment: It has nothing to do with the http headers. It is because of the difference in encoding of the multiform data part. Compare the two versions in my answer "Dart/ASCII" to "Dart/non-ASCII". Why don't you post a new question (tagged with your webserver) asking how to parse this in your webserver. You can post ascii / non-ascii versions.

Comment: Have you tried @DannyTuppeny's suggestion? Use `ParseMultipartForm` at the server? Do you really need to post a multipart form (what's driving this)? Would a regular form do instead?

Comment: Added an additional answer with a workaround for the Go server bug. No guarantees as the the quality of my Go code, as this is the first time I ever looked at Go!

Answer (score 2):

The problem, it appears, is in `formdata.go` part of `multipart`. Go assumes that any multipart part with an `Content-Type` header is a file (not a field). However, knowing this you can change your server code as follows:

```
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.POST("/sotest", func(c *gin.Context) {

        formValue := c.PostForm("form_value")

        if formValue == "" {
            formFile, _ := c.FormFile("form_value")
            file, _ := formFile.Open()
            b1 := make([]byte, formFile.Size)
            file.Read(b1)
            formValue = string(b1)
        }

        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "status":    "posted",
            "formValue": formValue,
        })
    })
    r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
}
```

When you detect that `PostForm` returns the empty string, you know that Go has treated the field as a file, in which case you can Open and Read the 'file' and decode it as the utf-8 string that we know it is. Obviously, you could encapsulate the "try as PostForm and if that's empty, try as FormFile" test into a function.

If you don't want to have to test for empty string at the server, you could change your Dart end code to always utf-8 encode even non-ascii strings with

```
request.files.add(
  new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    'some_form_value_name',
    utf8.encode('the string value'),
    contentType: new MediaType('text', 'plain', {'charset': 'utf-8'}),
  ),
);
```

and read them at the server with the Open/Read/string method.

Comment: Thanks for your clarify. This seem a further clear to this question. However, change Dart code or golang code seems all treat this none-English field as a file field, but when I post English words the server can  receive it correctly. I think that is the main question. (Not just write a simply string as file, it's complicated and inelegant)

Comment: If you just change the go code as I show, there is no need to change the dart end.